# How to install PrimeFaces as Wildfly module?

Tags: primefaces, wildfly

I'm using WF 14.0.1.Final and trying to install Primefaces 6.2 as a module.
I've added dependencies towards javax.faces in `module.xml` file: 
`<dependencies>
   <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
 </dependencies>`


Then I set the scope `<provided>` in mvn `pom.xml` of my application for Primefaces and add a reference towards primefaces module in jboss-deployment-structure.

The problem is that there is no errors in the log when I deploy the application but my shows empty page meaning it didn't have primefaces tags to create page.

When set primefaces to be a global Wildfly module everything works perfectly. Something in WF triggers Primefaces initialization or whatever but I don't know how all this works.

Comment: Any stacktrace in the error?

Comment: @Kukeltje I've updated my post with stacktrace

Comment: The stacktrace is hard to read certainly om my phone. Can you better format it?